# Lightning splitter - charging and external device connection

Tags: iphone, lightning

Are lightning splitters thats supports charging and external device available on the market?
I want to use my iphone with irig keyboard or pads when it is charging.

Comment: It exists on my iphone and ipad and also I have few device that can be used with ios via lightning cable. Problem that I cannot plug device into charge when I’m use it.

Comment: Yes, you can find them on the bay of fleas - I don't have one so I don't know, but they advertise playing music and charging at the same time.